# Example of a "bleeding" raster in GIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I was reading an ArcGIS Help page recently on [Polygon to Raster (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000030000000) GP tool. There is piece of information there that I became interested in:

> If **"bleeding"** or stripes occur in the output raster then use the Check
>   Geometry and Repair Geometry tools to correct the input feature data.

Can anyone describe what bleeding is in terms of a GIS raster dataset / satellite imagery data and if possible supply an image for illustrating this phenomenon.

Comment: This may be a good lead: http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31413

Comment: Imagine what will happen with a half-scan fill algorithm with an unclosed polygon.  Or an improperly wrapped polygon (e.g., left hand rule in a shapefile).  Or a polygon with a "dangle".

Comment: @Vince, I got you. Is this applicable only when exporting a vector feature into a raster with a filling process? Can bleeding occur as a result of some processing for a casual raster dataset such as an elevation surface or a satellite imagery?

Comment: By definition, *bleeding* can only occur in vector-to-raster conversion.  DEMs can get their own artifacts, especially in contour generation (the cure for which is often to run a low-pass filter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ESRI has a [technical article](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31413) describing polygon "bleeding" when printing or exporting.  The apparent cause:

> Data layer with the polygon fill has broken geometry, which is causing
>   the fill symbology to bleed when printed or exported.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! It demonstrates the phenomenon perfectly.

Comment: I agree. That is an excellent answer. I think of striping in an image as more of a missing column (or row?) in an image. I've seen that in BIL or BIP files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good example of "bleeding" of a raster when using the 'Polygon to Raster' tool

[image: Here is a very good example of "bleeding" of a raster when using the 'Polygon to Raster' tool]

Comment: I think I figured out what was causing this issue as well - if the polygon feature class is in a different coordinate system than the workspace, it seems to cause the bleeding.  After I changed coordinate system to feature class coords, no more bleeding.